# Label existing image

Tags: windows, docker, caching, build, labeling

I'm calculating my DLL version before the build using some info from my source and git data.
I want also to expose that version as label of the image.

In order to do that I use powershell to read the final version to file:

```
RUN $version = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:\WebAPI\bin\WebAPI.dll').FileVersion; \
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\VERSION' -Value $version
```

Then, after the build I read that file and rebuild with --label argumet:

```
# Read version from image
$id = $(docker create my_image)
docker cp "${id}:C:\VERSION" version.txt
docker rm -v $id
$version = Get-Content -Path version.txt

# Rebuid with version label
docker build -t my_image --cache-from my_image --label version=$version .
```

It's working, but ugly, and the msbuild is never cached and takes too long to rebuild it all just for that label.

I'm looking for other ideas how to label with version that calculated inside the build, or, idea how to force docker to use the cache as is.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how to do it. One of them - add a hash string of the last git commit as a tag.

Get hash of the last commit:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Keep only 12 symbols of it:

```
git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c 1-12
```

Build it:

```
docker build <path> -t my_image:$(git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c 1-12)
```

After that you'll get something like this:

```
Successfully built 69a5823a74e6
Successfully tagged my_image:196957476da0
```

In this case, docker will use cache.